# ¿Cómo compartir audio mp3 manteniendo pulsado un botón?

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Buenas, estoy intentando poder compartir varios audios de mi carpeta raw a otra aplicación(whatsapp, gmail,etc) . A través de un botón, si clickeo se reproduce y si dejo pulsado quiero que me de la opción de compartir. Según he visto por internet una forma de compartir un archivo es creando un Intent, pero creándolo dentro del método de mantener pulsado, me da error en getPackageName. ¿Cómo podría solucionar ésto? Aqui parte de mi código:

```
final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cristobalmasgrande);
    Button button1 =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound1.start();
        }
    });

    button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            compartirAudio.setType("audio/*");
            compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + araujomio)); //En getPackageName() da error por no estar definido
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

***Resuelto en StackOverflow en inglés
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991989/how-to-share-sounds-with-a-long-click/47992152#47992152***

En la instancia de onLongClickListener no existe un método llamado getPackage(). Hay varias opciones, por ejemplo:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + v.getContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/" + araujomio));
```

o

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + araujomio));
```